# Compilation fails when importing DTCoreText in ObjC++ file

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, dtcoretext

I've been trying to import [`DTCoreText.h`](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) in a class with both Objective-C and C++ code, but it results in the following cryptic compilation errors:

[image: Compilation errors]

The code doesn't have syntax errors and works correctly when I use it in classes written exclusively in Objective-C, but if I change their extension to `.mm` the compilation fails. This indicates that is something related to the C++ compiler, but I'm not sure exactly what.

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening due to the fact that some method signatures had parameters with the name `class` which is a reserved keyword in C++ and eventually led to the compilation errors I've listed above.

Changing the parameters name fixed it.